# Rosserial arduino connection error

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am currently trying to connect my arduino due to my pc in order to run my ROS package I wrote, which shall communicate with the arduino.

I can compile and upload my program via the GUI. To start the serial connection, I run:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
```

Which produces the output:

```
[INFO] [1499369503.299387]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1499369503.305172]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [1499369520.430946]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I don't really understand the message. I wrote all my nodes in ROS kinetic and also installed rosserial via:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosserial
```

just like it was done in the tutorial.

Why is the arduino assigned to a particular ROS version anyway? How can I set this to kinetic?

I am working on a virtual box with Ubuntu 16.04

Does somebody know how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance,

Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265639/rosserial-arduino-connection-error/) by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-06**:\

> such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

this is an *example*. It does not refer to exact versions of anything. It's basically giving you one specific example of a cause for this issue (ie: using different versions of things).

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-07-06**:
I know. But still i have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It now works on an Arduino Mega 2650. Same settings, same code, works.

It even got the same amount of pins available.

---

Originally posted by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) with karma: 115 on 2017-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0